# how to match correct answer and question in game application

Tags: node.js, json, nosql, backend

I have implemented a game application in which there are four options and among them there is one answer. Options are randomly arranged. How can I check that selected option is a correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Keep an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` that associates question indices or questions with answers?

Answer (score 0):

This sould work,

```
const quiz = [
    {
        question: 'this is a question',
        answer: 'the answer',
        choices: []
    }
];

quiz.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.question);
    
    // im hardcoding the selected answer as an example be sure to dynamically populate this with the users input

    let selectedAnswer = 'the answer';
    if (selectedAnswer === item.answer) {
        console.log('correct answer');
    } else {
        console.log('incorrect answer');
    }
});
```